# Pandas category group by category sorting

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to be able sort the result of Pandas' 2nd groupby by Category.

The first groupby creates a list from another column, and second one is the groupby result I need. The problem is that the 2nd groupby does not honour the original sorted categorical index of the Dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy  as np
import numpy.ma as ma
from   pathlib import Path

fr   = Path('../data/rules-1.xlsx')
df   = pd.read_excel(fr, sheet_name='MS')
```

```
from pandas.api.types import CategoricalDtype

print('Before:')
display(df)
ms_cat         = ['Parent-C', 'Parent-A', 'Parent-B']
df['ParentMS'] = df['ParentMS'].astype(CategoricalDtype(list(ms_cat)),order=True)
df             = df.reset_index()
df             = df.set_index('ParentMS')
df             = df.sort_index()
print('After:')
display(df)

df_g           = df.  groupby(['ParentMS', 'Milestone'])['Tasks'].apply(list)
df_g           = df_g.groupby('ParentMS')

# Category sort is not honored after the second groupby()
for name, group in df_g:
    print(name, group)
```

```
This the input file:
[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZnZD.png
```

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input dataframe and your expected output, your question is a bit confusing without a proper [mcve]

Comment: I re-edited the original post

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two "df_g" lines did the trick for me. I cannot explain it but it worked

df_g = df.groupby(['ParentMS', 'Milestone'])['RN'].apply(list).groupby('ParentMS')